# How to measure the closest distance between complex meshes

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to set a curved mesh a precise distance from a very complex mesh.

I want to measure the distance from the closest point on a complex mesh to it's closest point on a curved mesh, preferably as different objects but I can combine them if this can only be done in edit mode.

The pic shows the complex mesh in black and the top most orange curve (selected part) is the other mesh I want to know the closest distance between. This is very zoomed in, it's much bigger...

The only way (I think) I found was using Python code, and I'm just not ready for that yet :)

I've only been using Blender for about 1 month, so I'm still a noob, please be kind!

[image: meshes in question...]

Comment: It is not something I have ever needed but there is the Ruler https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/ruler_protractor.html and also the included Measure IT add-on (incldued in Blender you just have to enable it) https://www.blendernation.com/2015/05/29/take-measurements-in-the-blender-viewport-with-measureit/

Comment: Thanks rob, I know about those 2.I just need an automatic way to find the 2 closest points between 2 meshes. The complex mesh is WAAAAAY to difficult to find the point I need

Comment: @Ash Python is the way to go here

Comment: Python huh WhatAMesh? I'll get to learning then :)